# Incrementing a column value in a SQL database if there is a duplicate record

Tags: sql-server

I have rows in database as follows:

```
DocumentNumber   LineNumber
1234             1
1234             1 
1453             1
1237             1
1677             1
```

These values are already stored in the database. What I need to do is incriment the linenumber column by 1 if there are multiple documentnumbers. So documentnumber 1234 will have linenumbers of 1 and 2.

Is there anyway to do this in an update statement?

Comment: Why do you want to store this LineNumber? Now it means you have to maintain it for the entire table every time a single row is added, changed or removed. Since you can derive this LineNumber at runtime, what is the point in storing it?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using SQL-Server 2005 or greater you could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT DocumentNumber, LineNumber
     ,   RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocumentNumber Order By DocumentNumber)
  FROM tableName
)
UPDATE CTE SET LineNumber = RN
```

[**Demo-Fiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d086/1/0)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using 2005 and cant use row number. I have an update tho. It looks like when I select * from the temp table (after the data has been inserted into it) the NewLineNum value for the last row is actually 2, but when it is inserted back into the actual chargebackdetail table, it gets updated as a 1. Does anyone know why this could be happening?